# $(||Tx_n||)$ is bounded for all $(x_n):x_n\to 0$ implies that $T$ bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove the next result:

*Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a normed vector space and $\Phi:X\longrightarrow X$ linear operator. If $(||\Phi x_n||)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded for all $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset X$ such that $x_n\to 0$, then $\Phi$ is bounded.*

It could be proved by *reductio ad absurdum*? Maybe using that $||\Phi x_n||\leq ||\Phi|| \cdot ||x_n|| $?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you want to use contradiction, you can't use $\|\Phi\|$ as you're assuming $\Phi$ is not bounded, so it does not have a norm.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose for a contradiction $\Phi$ is not bounded; then for every $n\geq 1$, there must exists $y_n\in X$ with $\|y_n\|=1$ and $\|\Phi y_n\|\geq n$. Define $x_n=\frac{y_n}{\sqrt{n}}$; then $\|x_n\|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, so that $x_n\to 0$; but $$\|\Phi x_n\|=\frac{\|\Phi y_n\|}{\sqrt{n}}\geq \sqrt{n},$$so $\Phi x_n$ is not bounded, which contradicts the hypothesis.